# ClickOnce won't update when running app from installed location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, deployment, clickonce

I have a simple WPF app I am using for some testing.

I am successfully deploying to a folder on my desktop.

Ex. **desktop\myApp\publish**

The install location is the same folder.

Other settings:

- Available offline: TRUE
- The application will check for updates: TRUE
- Automatically Increment Revision: TRUE

Under Update Settings:

- Check For updates before application start: TRUE
- Specify a minimum version required: TRUE

I am unsure what I am doing wrong and not sure if I fully understand this.

So the application was successfully installed from the publish folder setup file. But when I publish updates and launch the app from start menu it does not update. I can get it to update by running setup again from publish folder but users are going to be launching from their start menu or a desktop icon created from install location.

**Is there a way to get it to update when launching the app from the location it was installed at?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installation location **MUST** be set to **UNC** or **file share** in order for it to check for updates.

If you are testing locally.... use this prefix for to locate file on c drive locally:

\\localhost\c$\